# Accessing variable access from a function in a class php

Tags: php

I am working with a php class.I declared a property in the class then in constructor i defined its value.But i am not getting that value from another method.

### My codes are

```
class Myclass
{
    var $prefix;
    public function __construct( $prefix )
    {
        $this->$prefix = $prefix;
    }         

    public static function ImageContent(){
       echo $prefix;
    }
}
```

### class instantiation

```
$content = new Myclass('the_foody_');
$content::ImageContent();
```

### when i deduct `static` it doesnot also echo anything.

```
$content->ImageContent();
```

Comment: Do you know how static functions work? They are called before the constructor.

Comment: Why is `ImageContent` static if you call it on an instance? Even if it wasn't static, `$prefix` doesn't exist in that functions scope. So that's two things to look up, statics and variable scope.

Comment: dont u got any errors ?

Comment: u cannot access non-static property inside static functions

Comment: so what i will do now @AbuHurairaLakdawala?i dont get any error

Comment: make ur class varaible as static

Comment: @AbuHurairaLakdawala I deducted `static` and added this `$content->ImageContent();` but not works yet

Comment: @muazssmc You haven't read comments have you...

Comment: can u update ur new code in ur question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access from the static function.In case you remove `static` then it would be

```
class MyClass {
  public $prefix;
  public function __construct($prefix) 
  {
    $this->prefix = $prefix;
  }

  public function ImageContent(){
     return $this->prefix;
  }
}

$myClass = new MyClass('the_foody_');
echo $myClass->ImageContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's important to keep in mind that **static functions** are called even before the class is being instantiated i.e it's called before calling a constructor.

One way to overcome your issue is by passing a parameter $prefix to this function.

If you want to remove **static**, try the below approach:

```
class MyClass {

    public $prefix;

    public function __construct($prefix) 
    {
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
    }

    public function ImageContent(){
       return $this->prefix;
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass('the_foody_');
echo $myClass->ImageContent();           // the_foody_
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.methods

Comment: can i deduct `static`?

Comment: Not sure if you needed it in the first place.

Comment: I deducted `static` and added this `$content->ImageContent();` but not works yet

Comment: Please follow my edited answer. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: @muaz have you also changed `$this->$prefix = $prefix;` to `$this->prefix = $prefix;`?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator works :) but when i again want to access this property then it says : `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property`
like : `$post_image = rwmb_meta( $this->$prefix . 'blog_image',  get_the_ID() );`

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing your entire code. Also, it's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve here

Comment: @desiDesign You are using variables wrong. You only need one `$` so `$this->$prefix` should be `$this->prefix`